# Proof of e as it approaches infinity

Tags: calculus

$$ e = \lim_{x \to ∞}(1+\frac{1}{x})^x $$

I think this is relevant from my textbook:

$$ \lim_{x \to ∞} \frac{e^x}{x^n} = ∞ $$
for all values of n.

How do I connect the two? Am I incorrect that they are related?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your definition of $e$?  One definition of $e^a$ is $e^a = \lim_{x \to ∞}(1+\frac{a}{x})^x$, from which we can just plug in $a=1$.  I suspect you have a different one, so we need to know where to start.  The equation you suspect is relevant is unlikely to help, as it would be true if we replaced $e$ by $2$, so it does not help in defining $e$

Comment: The second calculation would help more if the limit existed...

Comment: @RossMillikan The only other thing I can find related in my textbook is the following(Its just x replaced with n...): $e= \lim_{n \to ∞}(1+\frac{1}{n})^n $ Sorry I'm not very strong with proofs so I'm having ah ard time figuring out what's useful and what isn't.

Comment: The second property isn't related to the properties of $e$; the same limit holds for other constants. For instance, $$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{10^x}{x^n} = \infty.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second limit cannot be used to determine $e$ as pointed out by Theophile.

Here is a proof for the first limit using only the properties of exponential functions and the definition of the derivative. I am not 100% sure of its validity and would appreciate any constructive criticism.

Define $e$ as the value of the base of the exponential function whose derivative equals itself
$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x =\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=e^x
$$
so 
$$\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {e^{h}-1}{h}=1 
$$

Consider the function $$f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {x^{h}-1}{h}$$
which is well defined for $x>0$ and possesses the inverse function ...
$$f^{-1}(x)=\lim_{h \to 0}(1+xh)^{\frac 1h}$$

So

$$e=f^{-1}(1)=\lim_{h \to 0}(1+h)^{\frac 1h}$$
now making the substitution $x\equiv \frac 1h$ we get ...
$$e=\lim_{x\to \pm \infty }(1+\frac 1x)^{x}$$

which includes the expression you were asked to prove.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, we have

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n$$

Taking the log of both sides and applying log rules and L'Hospital's rule,

$$\begin{align}\ln(L)&=\ln\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n\right)\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\ln\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n&\text{bijective}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac xn\right)}{1/n}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac1{1+\frac xn}\cdot\left(-\frac x{n^2}\right)}{-1/n^2}&\text{L'Hospital's}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac x{1+\frac xn}\\&=x\end{align}$$

Thus,

$$\ln(L)=x\implies L=e^x$$

Comment: A little remark: this proof assumes that the definition of $e^x$ is the inverse function of natural logarithm.

Comment: @user3313320 That it is by definition.

Comment: The OP is using the def $e = \lim (1 + \frac 1x)^x$ which is fine.  IMO I think we and the OP can assume the basic definitions of real exponents and logarithms have be defined and verified.  If not, they can be varified by any calculus textbooks before starting the question.

Comment: @user3313320 Even more, he is assuming the derivative of $\ln$ is $\frac{1}{x}$ and this relies somehow on $e$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus Technically $\ln x$ can be defined as the antiderivative of $\frac 1x$

Answer (score 0):

$\lim \frac {e^x}{x^n} = \lim \frac{e^x}{e^{\ln x^n}} = \lim e^{x - n\ln x}$

Let $f(x) = x-n\ln x$ so $f'(x) = 1 - n\frac 1x > 0$ when $x > \max(0,n))$ so increasing for $x > n$.  $f''(x) = nx^{-2} > 0$ when $x > 0$ so $f(x)$ is increasing without asymptote for $x > \max(n,0)$. So $\lim x - \ln x = \infty$.

So $\lim e^{x-n\ln x} = e^{\lim(x-n\ln x)} = \infty$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** For each $x>0$ define $n_x=\lfloor x \rfloor$.

Then 
$$1+\frac{1}{n_x+1} \leq 1+\frac{1}{x} \leq 1+\frac{1}{n_x}\\
\left( 1+\frac{1}{n_x+1}\right)^{n_x} \leq \left( 1+\frac{1}{x} \right)^x \leq \left( 1+\frac{1}{n_x} \right)^{n_x+1}
$$

Now, use the fact that 
$$\lim_{n} \left( 1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n+1}=\lim \left( 1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n}=e$$
and the fact that $n_x$ is an integer.